# How to get the current running camera instance and give a particular file as input in IOS Real Device?

Tags: automation, appium, appium-ios

The problem
Can I get the current running camera instance and and give a particular file as input in IOS Real Device
Is this possible with appium ?
Please Advise

More Details:
I am trying to feed my camera an image during runtime. So basically my application has a feature: search a product by scanning a barcode, Since I am trying to automate this, I want to provide an image with barcode and have camera take that image while scanning.

Environment
Appium version: 1.3.2
Desktop OS/version used to run Appium: MAC OS High Sierra (10.13.4)
Mobile platform/version under test: iPhone 8 Plus, OS 11.3
Real device or emulator/simulator: REAL DEVICE
Please Advise

Comment: Hey @Dev, did you find solution to this?

Answer (score 1):

Appium is a black-box testing framework, so it cannot set image for your app directly in the runtime.

However, Appium exposes `push_file` functionality that **places a file onto the device in a particular place**.

For iOS it works only on **Simulators** (running Xcode SDK 8.1+)

```
driver.pushFile(
   "/path/to/device/image.jpg",
   new File("/Users/dev/files/image.jpg")
);
```

If your app supports image selection from gallery, you can push file and then select it in the gallery.

In case it doesn't work, you may look into writing tests directly using XCTest/XCUITest framework